# Attribute routing - can I specify default values for parameters not in the route

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have an action which returns a file.  It can either open it in the user's browser or download it directly to their PC.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Open(int Id, bool Download)
{
    ....
}
```

Via conventional routing I can define routes for downloading vs opening the file:

```
// Download the file
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "FileDownload",
    template: "File/Download/{id}",
    defaults new { controller "File", action = "Open" download = true });     

// Open file in browser
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "FileView",
    template: "File/View/{id}",
    defaults new { controller "File", action = "Open" download = false });
```

I am thinking of switching to attribute based routing.  I was wondering if there is any way to specify a default for the download parameter when it's not part of the route path.

```
[Route("[File/View/{id}", Name="FileView")]
[Route("[File/Download/{id}", Name="FileDownload")]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if it's directly possible, but why not simply use overloading?

You'll have something like this:

```cs
[Route("[File/View/{id:int}", Name="FileView")]
public async Task<IActionResult> View([FromRoute] int id)
{
    return await Open(id, false);
}

[Route("[File/Download/{id:int}", Name="FileDownload")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Download([FromRoute] int id)
{
    return await Open(id, true);
} 

private async Task<IActionResult> Open(int Id, bool Download)
{
    ....
}
```